# How to view json file in a multiple lines instead of a single long line

Tags: json

I tried multiple text editors to view a json file, only can see a long line, instead of well structured, more readable multiple lines:

[image]

Is there a tool that show json file contents in multiple lines? or Can I configure an editor such as notepad++, visual studio or spyder to view Json in multiple lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one I always use: http://json.parser.online.fr/
and Notepad++ has the feature to view and format JSON files too.
[image: Notepad++ JSON Viewer]

Answer (score 0):

To view json in a structured way, you have you use pretty-print. These are mostly available in the browsers too, so check where this functionality is in your specific browser.or you can use this website just copy and paste it here
https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print

Answer (score 0):

A json file is just a text file. If it is in one line, it is because it was saved in one line.

There are online validators that will beautify it for you, though.

https://jsonlint.com/

There are also methods in most modern programming languages for doing so.